# .NET Web Service logging with Log4Net not working from separate client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, log4net

In a basic .NET web service (asmx) which I am building locally, I'm trying to log using Log4NET to a file.  This works fine if I fire up debugging mode in Visual Studio and test the service using the wsdl/test pages provided.  But if I try using a separate client (I made a C# console app to call the service), I see the expected response, but get NO logging.
(The separate client code is listed below.  I had to import a reference to the built DLL of the web service.)

I'm a bit new to this, but I speculate the issue is because outside of the VS server or IIS (which I am stuck without), Global.asax is not used (which contains my initialization command for logging).  But I need to test from an external client.  How can I get Global.asax to initialize from the client application perspective, or how can I avoid needing to?  Does this sound like it would solve my logging issue?

Global.asax in my web service project contains this statement:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

And my separate client (console) application looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyWebService proxy = new MyWebService();

    MyWebService.Request request = new MyWebService.Request();
    request.Type = "Test";

    MyWebService.Response response = proxy.GetResponse(request);

    Console.WriteLine("RESPONSE CODE: " + response.StatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine("RESPONSE MSG: " + response.StatusMessage);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

I'm also unclear how I would change this console app to reference the Visual Studio server instance (ex: localhost:1583/MyWebService.asmx?op=GetResponse) instead of creating a proxy instance of the web service.  I think that would also do the trick, since the Visual Studio server utilizes Global.asax, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The simpler way

would be to move the log4net initialization inside `static void Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Don't forget to include `log4net` configuration in `app.config` file of your new host.

### The better way

would be to move your service to separate project (it is already so, right?) so it is complied into it's own assembly. Than apply

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

attribute to the `assemlyInfo.cs`. Refer to [log4net configuration manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) for details (search for word `assembly` on the page). This way is better, because you'll not have to add that

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

into the initialization of all host environments you have.

But make sure you have your log4net configuration in `app.config`, `web.config` or whatever configuration file you have.

Comment: Both methods worked perfect; I have modified my project to use the second method so that any client apps I create will only need the .config file changes.  Question; assuming the final product is deployed to IIS, it won't matter the client application config, since it will be using the server config, right?  (i.e. when a client is calling the service using the URL and passing a SOAP message)

Comment: Yes, client config is irrelevant for on-server logging. If you want to log on client too, there should be separate copy of log4net, configuration file, log4net initialization, etc. on client. But these two configurations/initializations do not interfere in any way.